# Why is my class not showing up in autocomplete?

Tags: actionscript-3

My class was not showing up in autocomplete. It was part of another file and I copied it into it's own file.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it was not showing up was because it was marked internal.

```
package com.example.model
{

    /**
     * Holds data. 
     * */
    internal class ChartItemData extends Item {

    }

}
```

The part that was confusing was that it was the only class inside the package. I didn't know you could do that.

I changed it to public and it was immediately visible.